# Protobuf message does not implement protoreflect.ProtoMessage (ProtoReflect method has pointer receiver)

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-go

I have a Protobuf message that imports `"google/protobuf/any.proto"`:

```
message MintRecord {
    ...
    google.protobuf.Any data = 11;
    ...
}
```

And I am trying to serialize another protobuf inside of the `data` field using anypb:

```
data, err := anypb.New(protobuf.LootcratePrize{
    Items: &protobuf.Inventory{Items: items},
    Roll:  fmt.Sprintf("%f", roll),
})
if err != nil {
    log.Println("[Lootbox] Err: error marshalling lootcrate prize data into mintRec", err)
} else {
    mintRecordProto.Data = data
}
```

Upon compilation I get the following error:

```
cannot use protobuf.LootcratePrize{…} (value of type protobuf.LootcratePrize) as type protoreflect.ProtoMessage in argument to anypb.New:
    protobuf.LootcratePrize does not implement protoreflect.ProtoMessage (ProtoReflect method has pointer receiver)
```

According to [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb) I am doing nothing out of the ordinary here. How do I resolve this issue?

This is the protobuf I am attempting to serialize and store inside of the `data` field:
Lootcrate.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;
option go_package = "protobuf/";

import "protobuf/inventory.proto";
import "protobuf/flowerdbservice.proto";

message LootcratePrize {
    Inventory items = 1;
    repeated NFT flowers = 2;
    string roll = 3;
}
```

Comment: Did you try passing a pointer `&protobuf.LootcratePrize{...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sarath Sadasivan Pillai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898494/sarath-sadasivan-pillai) is correct.
Change your code to :

```
data, err := anypb.New(&protobuf.LootcratePrize{
    Items: &protobuf.Inventory{Items: items},
    Roll:  fmt.Sprintf("%f", roll),
})
```